# Difference between $.ajax and $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.post( url, data, callback, type ); 
$.ajax ()
```

Could i know the difference between $.post and $.ajax. Which is preferable and how many parameters could we pass to $.ajax.

Comment: I would suggest you read the documentation ([$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)).

Comment: You forgot to put `$.get()` in the question too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are very similar (except by default `$.ajax` uses type=get, you have to change it to type=post).  You have a little more control over stuff with `$.ajax`, but `$.post` is a little simpler.  Think of `$.post` as a short-hand way of doing an AJAX POST.

For more information about `$.ajax` see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

More information about `$.post` see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/